# Close Vote Queue - Trust, but Verify

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close

I propose that, in addition to existing checks for votes, answers, etc., we put items in the Close Vote Queue On Hold automatically when

- there is a flag or close vote, at least a month old
- it is a month since the last activity on the post
- the post still has fewer than 100 views

When such items are put On Hold, they *get added to the Re-Open queue.*
So instead of a "verify four times", we would have a "trust, but verify" workflow.
Precise thresholds may need tuning.
(This feature might be appropriate only for Stack Overflow in the SE family.)

*Supporting case*

There is a long tail of few-viewed items in the CVQ.
These leave the queue when they get reviewed out, or eventually, soon after they hit 100 views.
We know that flagging and close-voting is generally quite accurate, but we have a safety mechanism, that requires 5 people to agree to close.
This works fine when a post is queued, reviewed, then put on hold or left open in short order.
For rarely viewed items though, its not working.
There simply aren't enough people active in "fringe" tags to get a post through the review cycle.
I think most people who are active and might choose to vote would likely see a post in the first month.

It's a waste to have close-worthy items demoralise reviewers by their quantity for months, only to quietly leave the queue as if nothing happened when they hit 100 views.
I believe that there are quite a number of close-worthy posts in lesser tags that go un-flagged at the moment.
Similarly, there are some high-volume tags where those who do good are overwhelmed by trash.
If we were to try harder to flag/vote-to-close these, we'd see the CVQ grow still more - wait, we do see that...

*Also...*

The last activity criterion could be set to some longer period initially then shortened.
This would dump extra items to the Reopen queue each day, until this part of the CVQ backlog is "cleared".

Comment: What if the percentage of older posts in the review queue that needs to remain *open* is larger than you think it is?

Comment: Then this would be inappropriate. But I understand that most flagging and voting is accurate.

Comment: This would cause a large mass of questions to be closed at once, which would cause some problems and/or turn some heads.

Comment: Looking at what gets approved in the Suggested Edit review queue, I am not so optimistic.

Comment: I like where your head's at, but doesn't this just shift the problem of review from one queue to another? Instead of a gigantic Close queue that's impossible to work through, we'd have a gigantic Reopen queue.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Part of the problem is the presentation of the problem itself, so even a change in the appearance of the issue could be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "presentation", @Mansfield. You think people would be more willing or able to slog through Reopen reviews?

Comment: @Mansfield: there are other proposals here on Meta to alter the appearance in less drastic ways. Why is this proposal better?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Well, they'd be able to do both. And they might be less intimidated by two smaller queues as opposed to one large one.

Comment: What we really need is stats on numbers of questions that leave the queue as "leave open" with counts of how many close votes they have.  If there are lots of questions that should be left open with 2, 3, or 4 close votes then it means that requiring the full 5 votes is helping to ensure the proper action is taken.  If there are almost no questions left open once they have, 2 (or 3 or 4) or more votes on them then it's an indication that, at least in this queue, that is all of the votes needed.  Where's the Shog signal?

Comment: @gunr2171 - agreed, hence I think the selection criteria should be set differently at the outset, to "trickle" items into the ROQ.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - I think that can be handled by a bit of throttling. I agree with other commenters who say that ROQ has a different mindset too.

Comment: Okay, the "splitting" idea makes sense, @Mansfield.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I can't find a counter argument to your point. But hopefully as there's no rep to gain from flagging and voting, the "signal/noise" is higher than in suggested edits.